# OpenGL ES 2.0 and default FrameBuffer in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm a bit confused about FrameBuffers. 
Currently, to draw on screen, I generate a framebuffer with a Renderbuffer for the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` using this code.

```
-(void)initializeBuffers{

    //Build the main FrameBuffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    //Build the color Buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

    //setup the color buffer with the EAGLLayer (it automatically defines width and height of the buffer)
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:EAGLLayer];
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &bufferWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &bufferHeight);

    //Attach the colorbuffer to the framebuffer
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

    //Check the Framebuffer status
    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    NSAssert(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, ERROR_FRAMEBUFFER_FAIL);

}
```

And I show the buffer content using

```
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318800/can-an-opengles-2-0-framebuffer-be-bound-to-a-texture-and-a-renderbuffer-at-the), I saw the comment of Arttu Peltonen who says:

> Default framebuffer is where you render to by default, you don't have
>   to do anything to get that. Framebuffer objects are what you can
>   render to instead, and that's called "off-screen rendering" by some.
>   If you do that, you end up with your image in a texture instead of the
>   default framebuffer (that gets displayed on-screen). You can copy the
>   image from that texture to the default framebuffer (on-screen), that's
>   usually done with blitting (but it's only available in OpenGL ES 3.0).
>   But if you only wanted to show the image on-screen, you probably
>   wouldn't use a FBO in the first place.

So I wonder if my method is just to be used for off-screen rendering. 
And in that case, what I have to do to render on the default buffer?! 
(Note, I don't want to use a GLKView...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The OpenGL ES spec provides for two kinds of framebuffers: window-system-provided and framebuffer objects. The default framebuffer would be the window-system-provided kind. But the spec doesn't require that window-system-provided framebuffers or a default framebuffer exist.

In iOS, there are no window-system-provided framebuffers, and no default framebuffer -- all drawing is done with framebuffer objects. To render to the screen, you create a renderbuffer whose storage comes from a `CAEAGLLayer` object (or you use one that's created on your behalf, as when using the `GLKView` class). That's exactly what your code is doing.

To do offscreen rendering, you create a renderbuffer and call `glRenderbufferStorage` to allocate storage for it. Said storage is not associated with a `CAEAGLLayer`, so that renderbuffer can't be (directly) presented on the screen. (It's not a texture either -- setting up a texture as a render target works differently -- it's just an offscreen buffer.)

There's more information about all of this and example code for each approach in Apple's [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW5).